# Can I create multiple __name__=="__main__" inside same jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I have a `.ipynb`  jupyter notebook file, where I am working.
The file contains multiple classes and methods. Some of them are dependent while some of them are not. For example:

```
class Node:
    ## this is where I create a single node

class LinkedList:
    ## this is where I create linked list
```

After this, I create another class where I inherit my base classes and implement algorithms.

```
class Solution:
    ## this is where I implement my algorithm

    method1():
        # method1 implementation
    
    method2():
        # method2 implementation
```

Finally, I create multiple mains in different cells below.

```
## main1 -- test case #1
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ## declare variables
   ## call classes and methods
   ## print something
```

In the next cell, I would do the following.

```
## main2 -- test case #2
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ## declare variables
   ## call classes and methods
   ## print something
```

Similarly, I would do this in next cell.

```
## main3 -- test case #3
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ## declare variables 
   ## call classes and methods
   ## print something
```

I like this template while solving leetcode problems locally. But I think while debugging, it's a little bit confusing.

**Is it a standard practice to do so in the jupyter notebook working environment? Does it mess up with scopes? Please help me understand if it a good practice, or recommend me how to run multiple test cases within the same jupyter notebook.**
Thank you so much for reading this far.

Comment: if you are just going to run a different cell for a different execution, you don't need the if __name__ conditional at all!  just put the sequence of calls you want in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Ummm, that's a little weird.

You have the right idea, wanting to keep things separate.
Just do it a bit differently,
use function definitions to accomplish your goal:

```
def main1():
    ...

def main2():
    ...

def main3():
    ...

main1()
main2()
main3()
```

---

Background: why do we use that `__main__` idiom at all?

Well, it originated long before Jupyter notebooks appeared on the scene.

A developer working on `def foo():`
will want to run it during testing,
and will commonly make the last lines of `foo.py` look like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('result was', foo())
```

Now, we *could* create a `foo_test.py` file,
but often the above will be most convenient.

Why not just a single-line call of `foo()`?
We protect the call for safe `import` by other modules.
Consider the nearby `baz.py` source file:

```
from foo import foo

def baz():
    return 2 * foo()
```

We wouldn't want that initial import line
to be noisy, or have other side effects
like changing a file or failing when a server's down.
The `if` protection lets other modules reliably import,
safe in the knowledge that only "boring" things
like class and function definitions will be happening.

In a notebook, we seldom encounter such considerations.
So a simple call to `main1()`, without an `if`, makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hadn't thought about creating multiple mains in python. Will definitely do it now.

Comment: Do feel free to give them more informative names than `mainN()`. (Recall that C uses `int main(argc, argv) { ... }` just as a conventional entry point -- no need to do that in python if you don't want to.)